# EmbededId with auto generated value does not have the generated id

Tags: hibernate, jpa

I have below table:

```
CREATE TABLE `contacts` (
  `id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `account_id` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`, `account_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=8 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I have the composite key defined for the id/account_id as below

```
@Table(name = "contacts")
@Entity
public class SalesContact
    implements Serializable {

    @EmbeddedId
    private CompositeKey key;

    @Column(name = "first_name")
    private String firstName;

    @Column(name = "last_name")
    private String lastName;


    public String getFirstName() {
        return firstName;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String firstName) {
        this.firstName = firstName;
    }

    public String getLastName() {
        return lastName;
    }

    public void setLastName(String lastName) {
        this.lastName = lastName;
    }

    public CompositeKey getKey() {
        return key;
    }

    public void setKey(CompositeKey key) {
        this.key = key;
    }
}
```

**Composite key:**

```
    @Embeddable
class CompositeKey implements Serializable {
    @Column(name = "account_id")
    @PartitionKey
    private Long accountId;

    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    public Long getAccountId() {
        return accountId;
    }

    public void setAccountId(Long accountId) {
        this.accountId = accountId;
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

When we try to insert into database, the auto generated id value is not available in the new record. The record is saved succesfully in the database. But the newly inserted record id is not available in the ORM.

```
EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
    // Do stuff...

    doInJPA( ()->entityManagerFactory, em -> {
        CompositeKey key = new CompositeKey();
        key.setAccountId(1L);

        SalesContact contact = new SalesContact();
        contact.setFirstName("John");
        contact.setKey(key);
        entityManager.persist( contact );

        Assertions.assertNotNull(key.getId());
    });

    entityManager.getTransaction().commit();
    entityManager.close();
```